# GTM Parse error. ')' expected _ GA + Oracle Bluekai tag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, parse-error

I have trouble finding out where I need to fix.
Where is the place that I need to insert ')'?

Error Code :

```
Parse error. ')' expected
on 3rd line, 75th letter  (This is translated.)
```

What I've done :

```js
// Maps 'dimension4' to 'BKUUID'.
gtag('config', 'UA-126592421-1', {'custom_map': {'dimension4': 'BKUUID'}});
__bluekai_data_sent = false;
function receiveMessage(event) {
if (event.origin === 'http://tags.bluekai.com' || event.origin === 'https://stags.bluekai.com') {
if (__bluekai_data_sent === false && typeof event.data !== 'undefined' && event.data.source === 'bluekai') {

// Declare BlueKai ID as custom dimension 4
gtag('event', 'bluekai_id_dimension', {'bluekai_id': event.data.bluekaiId}); 
__bluekai_data_sent = true;
}}}addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
return true;
```

Comment: Are you sure this snippet gives you the error?